# Backbone.Events eventsApi, why return true when name is not truth value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var eventsApi = function(obj, action, name, rest) {
  if (!name) return true;

  // code ...

  return true;
};
```

I don't know why the code here return true while !name. If I bind the event with a variable which is maybe undefined, the event will be bound on the obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter 'name' here means the event names which you want to bind to the object (the first parameter). Function eventsApi will return true if the name parameter is not support multi-events registration (Backbone's event API only supports string and object notation format, for example: "change click", {change: action, click: action2}).

If pass a non-string or non-object name parameter, events api will register a event handler for 'single event'. In your case, you try to register a custom event named undefined and backbone will regard it as a single event handler registration.

To sum up, the returned boolean value determines whether the event register need to do 'multi-events registration' or not.

```
....
on: function(name, callback, context) {
  //multi-events registration will be processed if the eventsApi function call return 'false'
  if (!eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) || !callback) return this;
  this._events || (this._events = {});
  var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
  events.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
  return this;
},
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that the event registration has take effect. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xAkM/)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder and answer has been updated. You could refer to it :)